# When should I use on* DOM properties vs on* HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript

So I have the option of using the 2 implementations below to keep track of which li element was clicked.  The first one is just a

**Option 1:**

```
var ul = document.getElementById('inputField');
ul.onkeyup= function (event) {
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    var userInput = target.value;
    alert(userInput );
};
```

**Option 2:**

```
<input id="inputField" onkeyup="alert(userInput)" />
```

I understand that in the case above, the shorter one is more attractive.  However, if I plan to use several input fields, option 1 is more attractive as I won't have to take code every single attribute for each input field.  My question is...   Is there one method that is frowned over the other?

Comment: neither of them is attractive..just give the inputs a common class..and give that class your function that you are executing on keyup..jquery makes it pretty simple.Avoid inline coding..

Comment: I recommend to read about the different ways to attach event handlers [on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) ([inline](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html), [traditional](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html), [W3C](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)). It should highlight the (dis-)advantages of each method.

Comment: What's `getEventTarget`?

Comment: What is is about `li elements` ...? Here you will just alert the content of the input box?

Comment: @OPUS do you have a link to that example? Or a JSFiddle perhaps?

Comment: @OPUS: Not everyone wants to use jQuery.

Comment: @Rocket: Probably a method to deal with W3C/IE differences (`event.target` vs `event.srcElement`).

Comment: @FelixKling:i understand,but its possible using javascript too..

Comment: Felix Kling, agree - or any other library as well. Using huge libraries just for playing with events, values, elements and so on is totally overkill, and certainly not an good advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are equally bad, and frowned upon (as is using jQuery). Use `addEventListener`.

```
ul.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    // callback
});
```

If you want to be compatible with older browsers add a wrapper that check for `addEventListener` with a fallback to `attachEvent`.

Comment: `on*` attributes have more problems than the equivalent properties, which I'd argue are still useful on occasion.

Comment: I don't understand what prototypes and event listeners have in common. Old IE has `attachEvent`, hence the recommendation.

Comment: Not JS prototypes, application/website prototypes (I think) and in that case it easier to just use `on*` properties than dealing with `attachEvent` and `addEventListener`. Besides, `attachEvent` has its own problem that `this` does not refer to the element the handler is assigned to.

Comment: My fault for not being clear. By "prototyping" I meant quickly knocking up prototype, throwaway pages. Proof of concept pages, for example. It's just shorter and more compatible, and you don't always need the ability to add multiple listeners of the same type to every element.

Comment: Just use jQuery then? :P

Comment: I don't generally but it's a valid approach :)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know that addEventListener is the preferred approach.  If any of ya'll have any recommended links to tutorials and discussions, I would appreciate it if you can let me know. I'm new to JavaScript (and currently I'm trying to learn the basics without having to resort to JQuery).

Comment: I don't know any good tutorials, but if you see something cool: figure out how it works.

Comment: @ayjay: [See my comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831889/when-should-i-use-on-dom-properties-vs-on-html-attributes/18832033#comment27780324_18831889). It should cover everything you need to know about event handling.

Comment: I found this [tutorial](http://youtu.be/_Szdctv38Ow). It goes over the "old" ways which are the 2 I mentioned above, and then provides an example of the new method.  Thanks for the response Frits!

Comment: Oh dear God .. this is why I don't recommend tutorials. He preaches using `addEventListener` but still uses `window.onload`. Seriously, forget the tutorials. Look at real world examples.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, and I thought I found gold. LOL.  Got any "real world" example link?  Or perhaps, a JSFiddle you created?

Comment: I guesss, [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener) would be a good one.  And FelixKling's link above too.